# I want to prompt the sum of the numbers prompted before

Tags: javascript, sum

I am stuck.

I have to prompt a number. and then to create a cycle of prompts related with the intiial prompt and then sum them. I am completely lost. how can I sum them?

```
let first_question=prompt("introduce the quantity of numbers you want to sum")

for (let i=0; i < first_question;i++)
{
      
    let second_question= prompt ("introduce the number you want to sum");   
     

}
```

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, I dont know why the code shows like that....

Comment: You need a variable to store sum and add new input to it

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

```
var first_question = parseInt(prompt("Introduce the quantity of numbers you want to sum: "));
var sum = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < first_question; i++) { 
    let second_question = parseInt(prompt("Introduce the number you want to sum: "));  
    sum += second_question;
}
```

and at the end the variable sum will have the value you want.
Also note that prompt() will return a string, so I used parseInt() in order to transform it into a number